# How can I use URL rewriting using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have used the following rule for my URL rewriting. It works fine up to the second parameter. But when I use with the third parameter, it is not working.  For example, I use http://example.com/1/2/3 and it is not working, but with http://example.com/1/2 it is working.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ ./index.php?api=$1
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?api=$1&id=$2
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?api=$1&id=$2&action=$3
```

Comment: Hi hsve solve it by using

RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ ./index.php?api=$1
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)$ index.php?api=$1&id=$2
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)$ index.php?api=$1&id=$2&action=$3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, It worked for me.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ ./index.php?api=$1
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?api=$1&id=$2
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?api=$1&id=$2&action=$3
```

Answer (score 1):

This solved my problem.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ ./index.php?api=$1
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)$ index.php?api=$1&id=$2
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)$ index.php?api=$1&id=$2&action=$3 
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)$ index.php?api=$1&id=$2&action=$3&k=$4 
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/(.*)$ index.php?api=$1&id=$2&action=$3&k=$4&v=$5
```